# Difference between Site Owners and Site Admin in SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Can anyone help me to find the difference between Site Owners and Site Admin in SharePoint Server 2010.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint , There are

1. Sites (or Site Collection) and
2. Sub-site under Sites

Site Admin (Site Collection Admin):

- This Roles gives full control to Parent Site and all Sub-site under.
- This means this roles is for set (collection) of many sub sites.

Site Owner :

- This Role also gives full control , but specific to only to one sub-site.

Hence Site Admin Role is more powerful compared to Site Owner.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but in addition to Pravin B's answer, SCAdmin has access to all content and the ability to manage all groups.  They have access to the SCRecycle Bin and can undelete up to an additional 30 days(60 total).  They have an additional block of settings under site settings that Site Owners will never have access to.